# Badge Drawable not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

Why [BadgeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable) is not displayed anywhere? I'm trying to add on `MaterialCardView`, `MaterialButton` etc. It's not showing. Anyone have ideas how to fix this? Or have the same library that replacing this?

Here's code:

```
val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(holder.itemView.context)
badgeDrawable.number = 10
badgeDrawable.badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_END
badgeDrawable.backgroundColor = holder.itemView.context.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)
holder.itemView.home_cardview.overlay.add(badgeDrawable)
badgeDrawable.updateBadgeCoordinates(holder.itemView.home_cardview, null)
```

This method not working too:

```
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, anchor, null);
```

By the way in new version compatBadgeParent is required field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010998/5046642) posted by [@0X0nosugar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015207/0x0nosugar) on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009600/does-badgedrawable-not-work-for-views-within-a-framelayout-such-as-buttons-imag) so please go check out his answer and give him a thumbs up. Links placed above, thank you!

`BottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge()` does not only assign the `BadgeDrawable` as foreground Drawable, but it also sets the drawable bounds. Without this step, they stay at (0,0,0,0), so there is nothing to draw.

In order to set the bounds, let's introduce an extension function for `BadgeDrawable`

```
/**
 * Inspired by BadgeUtils in com.google.android.material library
 *
 * Sets the bounds of a BadgeDrawable 
 */
private fun BadgeDrawable.setBoundsFor(@NonNull anchor: View, @NonNull parent: FrameLayout){
    val rect = Rect()
    parent.getDrawingRect(rect)
    this.setBounds(rect)
    this.updateBadgeCoordinates(anchor, parent)
}
```

Use this function with your BadgeDrawable for FrameLayout:

```
private fun setFindShiftBadge(state: HomeState) {
    val findShiftsBadge = BadgeDrawable.create(this)
    // configure the badge drawable
    findShiftsBadge.badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_END
    findShiftsBadge.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite)
    findShiftsBadge.badgeTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
    findShiftsBadge.number = state.availableShifts.size
    // set bounds inside which it will be drawn
    findShiftsBadge.setBoundsFor(btn_badge, home_framelayout)
    // assign as foreground drawable
    home_framelayout.foreground = findShiftsBadge
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can apply the `BadgeDrawable` to a `MaterialCardView` or a `MaterialButton` using a layout as:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    ..>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            .../>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then just use the method **`BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable`**.

For example with a **`CardView`**:

```
    MaterialCardView cardview = findViewById(R.id.card);
    cardview.setClipToOutline(false);  //Important with a CardView

    cardview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(15);
            BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, cardview, findViewById(R.id.layout));

            cardview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

[image]

For a **`Button`**:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:id="@+id/button"
      ../>

</FrameLayout>
```

and then a similar code:

```
    button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(7);
            badgeDrawable.setBackgroundColor(......);
            badgeDrawable.setVerticalOffset(20);
            badgeDrawable.setHorizontalOffset(15);

            BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, button, findViewById(R.id.layout));

            button.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here I have implemented [`BadgeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable) using [`BadgeUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeUtils) with xml style to add badge on Button.

```
private fun setBadgeCount(count: Int) {
        BadgeDrawable.createFromResource(this, R.xml.badge_style).apply {
            number = count
            BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(this, binding.buttonContact)
        }
    }
```

**badge_style.xml:**

```
<badge xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Badge"
    app:backgroundColor="#FF0000"
    app:badgeTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:horizontalOffset="6dp"
    app:maxCharacterCount="2"
    app:verticalOffset="8dp" />
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:

1. https://material.io/develop/android/supporting/badge
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/package-summary

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function without **FrameLayout** in **Kotlin** way as:

**view** is the component where you want to put the notification badge!

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    private fun initBadge(view : View, nbrNotification : Int) {

        if(nbrNotification == 0) return // Don't show the badge

        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

            override fun onGlobalLayout() {

                BadgeDrawable.create(requireContext()).apply {
                    number = nbrNotification
                    verticalOffset = 70
                    horizontalOffset = 70
                    //badgeDrawable.setBackgroundColor() #to change the background color
                    BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(this, view)
                }

                view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

verify the version that are you using, I am using:

> com.google.android.material:material: 1.1.0-beta01

and try with this:

```
bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.menu_item_notifications).apply {
            backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.red)
            badgeTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.white)
            maxCharacterCount = 3
            number = 10 //should be change
            isVisible = true
        }
```

Comment: i dont wanna add badge on bottomNavigation, i want add badge to buttons or cardviews

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
It may be a bug in the Badge library.
This's work:

```
        badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(frameLayoutContainer.getContext());
        frameLayoutContainer.setForeground(badgeDrawable);
        frameLayoutContainer.addOnLayoutChangeListener((v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) -> {
            //
            badgeDrawable.updateBadgeCoordinates(frameLayoutContainer, frameLayoutContainer);
        });
```

frameLayoutContainer is a FrameLayout that sets BadgeDrawable to its foreground.

Comment: What are `iconParent` and `iconContainer`?

Comment: Sorry for Typo. iconParent is a FrameLayout that sets BadgeDrawable to its foreground.

Comment: @Mindgamer did any of these solutions work for you ?

Comment: @PrincepsPolycap no, nothing helped

Comment: Here is a link to the solution someone posted for me that ended up working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009600/does-badgedrawable-not-work-for-views-within-a-framelayout-such-as-buttons-imag

Answer (score 0):

```
    BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(this);
    badgeDrawable.setNumber(15);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_center);

    //core code
    frameLayout.setForeground(badgeDrawable);
    frameLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener((v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) -> {


        //either of the following two lines of code  work
        //badgeDrawable.updateBadgeCoordinates(imageView, frameLayout);
        BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, imageView, frameLayout);
    });





    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/iv_center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_beard" />
    </FrameLayout>
```