# Does BadgeDrawable not work for views within a FrameLayout such as buttons, images, textviews etc.?

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, android-framelayout, badge

I have this function in my main activity which doesn't display a badge:

```
private fun setFindShiftBadge(state: HomeState) {
        val findShiftsBadge = BadgeDrawable.create(this)
        home_framelayout.foreground = findShiftsBadge
        findShiftsBadge.badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_END
        findShiftsBadge.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite)
        findShiftsBadge.badgeTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
        findShiftsBadge.number = state.availableShifts.size
 }
```

In the same activity, I have this function which displays a badge:

```
private fun setMyPostedShiftBadge(state: HomeState) {
    val userShiftsBadge: BadgeDrawable =
        bottom_navigation_view.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.bottom_navigation_my_posted_shifts_text)
    userShiftsBadge.number = state.userShifts.size
    userShiftsBadge.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
}
```

Now I understand that the second function works because the badge is set within a `BottomNavigationView`. Ironically, `BottomNavigationView` extends `FrameLayout`. In the Android Documentation: 
[Add BadgeDrawable as a ViewOverlay to the desired anchor view using attachBadgeDrawable(BadgeDrawable, View, FrameLayout).
Update the BadgeDrawable BadgeDrawable's coordinates (center and bounds) based on its anchor view using updateBadgeCoordinates(View, ViewGroup).](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable)

They say to use this code, `For API 18+ (APIs supported by ViewOverlay)` which I use in the first function that doesn't work:

```
 BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context);
 BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, anchor, null);
```

I have also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402039/badge-drawable-not-showing) but it didn't work either. I'm aware there are workarounds such as:

1. Creating a drawable then setting that onto of the view you want
2. Placing a TextView within that drawable that you then update with the number you want
3. Toggle the visibility of the drawable when there are any numbers.

I am on `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'`

This seems dirty to me since I know that there is a better way to do this. I just can't seem to figure it out. What am I missing? Is this even possible? How have you been able to do this without having to write a workaround? Thanks for your time! Looking forward to learning from your questions and answers!! Have a fantastic day!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`BottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge()` does not only assign the `BadgeDrawable` as foreground `Drawable`, it also sets the drawable bounds. Without this step, they stay at (0,0,0,0), so there is nothing to draw.

In order to set the bounds, let's introduce an extension function for `BadgeDrawable`

```
/**
 * Inspired by BadgeUtils in com.google.android.material library
 *
 * Sets the bounds of a BadgeDrawable 
 */
private fun BadgeDrawable.setBoundsFor(@NonNull anchor: View, @NonNull parent: FrameLayout){
    val rect = Rect()
    parent.getDrawingRect(rect)
    this.setBounds(rect)
    this.updateBadgeCoordinates(anchor, parent)
}
```

Use this function with your `BadgeDrawable` for `FrameLayout`:

```
private fun setFindShiftBadge(state: HomeState) {
    val findShiftsBadge = BadgeDrawable.create(this)
    // configure the badge drawable
    findShiftsBadge.badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_END
    findShiftsBadge.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite)
    findShiftsBadge.badgeTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
    findShiftsBadge.number = state.availableShifts.size
    // set bounds inside which it will be drawn
    findShiftsBadge.setBoundsFor(btn_badge, home_framelayout)
    // assign as foreground drawable
    home_framelayout.foreground = findShiftsBadge
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I truly wonder how the Android documentation can be so useless.

Answer (score 6):

```
  BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(this);
badgeDrawable.setNumber(15);

FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_center);

//core code
frameLayout.setForeground(badgeDrawable);
frameLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener((v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) -> {


    //either of the following two lines of code  work
    //badgeDrawable.updateBadgeCoordinates(imageView, frameLayout);
    BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, imageView, frameLayout);
});





<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/iv_center"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_beard" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google (here), it has to know the sizes&locations of the views to put the badge, so you need to have the View inside a FrameLayout, and check for layout changes.

You can use this function to help you:

```
@androidx.annotation.OptIn(com.google.android.material.badge.ExperimentalBadgeUtils::class)
fun BadgeDrawable.attachToView(anchor: View, customBadgeParent: FrameLayout?) {
    BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(this, anchor, customBadgeParent)
    anchor.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
        updateBadgeCoordinates(anchor, customBadgeParent)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
badgeDrawable.attachToView(iconImageView, iconAndBadgeContainer)
```