# BadgeDrawable does not appear on elements other than BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-drawable, material-components-android

I'm having trouble getting [BadgeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable) to work.

There is no problem using it with `BottomNavigationView`

```
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
val badge = navView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.navigation_home)
badge.number = 12
```

But when I want to use it on other elements it wont show up. Like this:

```
val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context!!)
badgeDrawable.number = 32
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, textView, root.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout))
```

I'm using the FrameLayout only because [this issue fix](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1322) seems to be not shipped yet.

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm using the latest possible library version: 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-rc01'

I've tried different methods. No luck though. Is there a secret to it which I'm missing?

Here is a git repo with the project (as simple as possible): https://github.com/marcinkunert/badgeissue

[image: badge drawable not showing]

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        .../>

</FrameLayout>
```

and in your code:

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.text_home);
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context);
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(32);
            badgeDrawable.setBadgeGravity(BadgeDrawable.TOP_END);
            BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, imageView, findViewById(R.id.layout));
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you help me to solve my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73597146/how-to-add-badge-on-hamburger-navigation-menu-icon ?

Answer (score 1):

For now I've came up with this function:

```
fun addBadgeDrawable(count: Int, target: View, parent: FrameLayout, context: Context) {
    target.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context)
            badgeDrawable.number = count
            badgeDrawable.setBoundsFor(target, parent)
            parent.foreground = badgeDrawable
            target.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
}
```

Unfortunately the `BadgeUtils` are not working for me at the moment.

Here is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/issues_button_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/issues_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/c_gold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I suspect there will be issues with this solution in the near future. I'll try to update this answer if I'll find any.

The solution is mostly inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010998/1756721) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036962/12931715) answer and the xml from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252517/12931715) answer

```
 FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout)

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context);
        badgeDrawable.setNumber(32);
        badgeDrawable.setBadgeGravity(BadgeDrawable.BOTTOM_END);
        BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, imageView, framelayout);
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Depending on the gravity of your badge drawable, set padding accordingly. In my case, i want the badge to show at the bottom end.

```
          <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:paddingBottom="9dp"
                android:paddingEnd="13dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"            
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon" />

            </FrameLayout>
```